# Event Occurring in the Form Life Cycle in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

Which Event is occurred before `Form Load` event??

Because I have a `timer` control for which I have written `timer.start()` method in form load event and current time is displayed in `Label` Control.

`Timer` starts when the form Loads but it takes few seconds to show the time, so is there any other way to show the time fast?

Comment: What is the interval on your timer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a function called ShowTheTime.  Call it in form load.  Also start your timer in form load.  Your timer handler also calls ShowTheTime.

Am I missing something here?  It seems kind-of trivial.

Comment: The OP is already doing exactly what you're describing: calling start from the load event.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the Timer from the Forms namespace. That component is tightly coupled to the UI. You should take a look at the [Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) class which is not tied to the UI. You will have complete control over it and can start it from the Form's constructor (or even earlier, before the form is created.)

This is a [very old article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) but the concepts in it still hold. (Compares the different Timer classes.) Basically an [abbreviated version](http://csharptips.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/thread-timer/) of the previous article.